# How to get data from array in mongoose?

Tags: arrays, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am new to mongoose node.js and mongoDB, I have a db Schema like

```
Project:{
    projectName:"String",
    projectManager:"String",
    task:[{
           taskName:"String",
           timetakeninhrs:"String"
    }]
};
```

So what I want is to get only the details of task with particular task name.
I am writing sql script so that you can know what I want :

```
Select taskname,timetakeninhrs from project where taskName ='DB create';
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The **[`$elemMatch`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/projection/elemMatch/)** projection operator would come in handy for this:

```
Project
    .where('task.taskName', 'DB create') // or where('task.taskName').equals('DB create').
    .select({_id: 0, task: {$elemMatch: {'taskName': 'DB create'}})
    .exec(function(err, docs){
        var tasks = docs.map(function(doc){ return doc.task[0]; });
        console.log(tasks[0].taskName); // 'DB create'
        console.log(tasks[0].timetakeninhrs); // '3'
    });
```

In the above, the **[`where()`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#query_Query-where)** method acts as a static helper method of the Mongoose model that builds up a query using chaining syntax, rather than specifying a JSON object. So

```
// instead of writing:
Project.find({ 'task.taskName': 'DB create' }, callback);

// you can instead write:
Project.where('task.taskName', 'DB create');

// or
Project.where('task.taskName').equals('DB create');
```

and then chain the **[`select()`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#schematype_SchemaType-select)** method to project the 'task' array field using **[`$elemMatch`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/projection/elemMatch/)**. In the **[`exec()`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#query_Query-exec)** method (which executes the query asynchronously), you need to pass in a callback which follows the pattern `callback(error, results)`. What results is depends on the operation: For **`findOne()`** it is a potentially-null single document, **`find()`** a list of documents, **`count()`** the number of documents, **`update()`** the number of documents affected, etc. In this case this returns an array of documents in the format:

```
[
    /* 0 */
    {
        "task" : [ 
            {
                "taskName" : "DB create",
                "timetakeninhrs" : "3"
            }
        ]
    },
    /* 1 */
    {
        "task" : [ 
            {
                "taskName" : "DB create",
                "timetakeninhrs" : "9"
            }
        ]
    }
    /* etc */
]
```

In your callback you can do a bit of data manipulation to get an object that only has those properties you specified, hence the use of the native JavaScript **[`map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)** function to create a new array of objects with those fields

Answer (score 1):

i create this example that  can help you:

```
var async=require('async');
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;
var uri = 'mongodb://localhost/myDb';
mongoose.connect(uri);

// define a schema
var ProjectSchema = new Schema({
    projectName: "String",
    projectManager: "String",
    task: [{
        taskName: "String",
        timetakeninhrs: "String"
    }]
});

// compile our model
var Project = mongoose.model('Project', ProjectSchema);

// create a documents
var Project01 = new Project({
    projectName: "Project01",
    projectManager: "Manager01",
    task: [{
        taskName: "tsk01_Project01",
        timetakeninhrs: "1111-1111"
    }, {
        taskName: "tsk02_Project01",
        timetakeninhrs: "1111-2222"
    }, {
        taskName: "tsk03_Project01",
        timetakeninhrs: "1111-3333"
    }, {
        taskName: "tsk04_Project01",
        timetakeninhrs: "1111-4444"
    }]
});

var Project02 = new Project({
    projectName: "Project02",
    projectManager: "Manager02",
    task: [{
        taskName: "tsk01_Project02",
        timetakeninhrs: "2222-1111"
    }, {
        taskName: "tsk02_Project02",
        timetakeninhrs: "2222-2222"
    }, {
        taskName: "tsk03_Project02",
        timetakeninhrs: "2222-3333"
    }, {
        taskName: "tsk04_Project02",
        timetakeninhrs: "2222-4444"
    }]
});

//delete existing documents and create them again
Project.remove({}, function() {
    Project01.save(function() {
        Project02.save(function() {
            //for example we find taskName: "tsk03_Project02"
            Project.find({'task': {$elemMatch: {taskName: "tsk03_Project02"}}},'task.taskname task.timetakeninhrs',function(err, docs) {
                if (!err) {
                    console.log(docs);
                }
            });
        });
    });
});
```