# MongoDb, NodeJs - How to find a document by searching it by id of an array element

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

This is my Model :-

```
   "_id":{
      "$oid":"5f0dbca73ef98355649d7cc7"
   },
   "name":"Multiple Image test",
   
   "description":"Awesome",
   
   "price":{
      "$numberInt":"15000"
   },
   "images":[
      {
         "_id":{
            "$oid":"5f0dbca73ef98355649d7cc9"
         },
         "data":{
            "$binary":{
               "base64":"random buffer data",
               "subType":"00"
            }
         },
         "contentType":"image/jpeg"
      },
      {
         "_id":{
            "$oid":"5f0dbca73ef98355649d7cc8"
         },
         "data":{
            "$binary":{
               "base64":"Random buffer data",
               "subType":"00"
            }
         },
         "contentType":"image/jpeg"
      }
   ],
   
   
}
```

Now how can i access a particular image data from the **images** field ?

I am using mongoose js so which query can be used and how to use it to access the data. Any kind of help would be appreciated.

Comment: Hope the answer of this thread will solve your problem [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33274927/how-to-get-data-from-array-in-mongoose](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33274927/how-to-get-data-from-array-in-mongoose)

Comment: did you want the whole document to be returned including the other fields. or just want to get one particular sub-document from your `images` array?

Answer (score 0):

And to boil Asiri's comment into something that fits your case:
You use the $elemMatch operator: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/elemMatch/

`MyModel.find({'images': {$elemMatch: {_id: ObjectId("5f0dbca73ef98355649d7cc8")}}}`

You might not need the cast to ObjectId. (Now you should be able to guess that I haven't tested this answer, and for that I'm profoundly sorry.)